# How to inject an object that is annotated with @InjectMock

Tags: java, mocking

Suppose I have the following code

```
class Player {
  @Inject
  Player(Tool tool) ...
}

class Game {
  @Inject
  Game(Player player) ...
}

@Mock Tool tool;

@InjectMocks Player player;
```

How would I automatically inject `Player` into `Game`?

Ideally I'd like to just do

```
@InjectMocks Game game;
```

But seems I need to

```
@BeforeEach
void setup() {
  game = new Game(player);
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to inject a mock `Player` into `game` or a real one? The title makes it sound like you want a mock, but the code in the question makes it look like you want a real one. Please edit the question to clarify.

Comment: Sorry, that was confusing. I updated the title. I want to inject a real `Player` object into `game`

Answer (score 0):

## Mocked object injection

If you want to use mocked `Player` in tests you should use `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks`.
Suggestion to add `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` which has built in method call `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` in `@BeforeEach` method.

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class GameTest {

  @Mock
  private Player player;

  @InjectMocks
  private Game game;
  
  @Test
  void getPlayer() {
    when(player.getPlayer()).thenReturn("player1");
    var gamePlayer = game.getPlayer();
    assertEquals("player1", gamePlayer);
  }

}
```

---

## Real object injection

Real object injection has nothing with mockito. Mockito framework is used to mock objects to test unit, not full flow.
**How to use real object - depends on used framework**.

## Spring

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Tool.class, Player.class})
class GameTest {

  @Inject
  private Game game;

  @Test
  void getPlayer() {
    var gamePlayer = game.getPlayer();
    assertEquals("player1", gamePlayer);
  }

}
```

## Spring-boot

```java
@SpringBootTest
class GameTest {

  @Autowired
  private Game game;

  @Test
  void getPlayer() {
    var gamePlayer = game.getPlayer();
    assertEquals("player1", gamePlayer);
  }

}
```

## No framework

```java
class GameTest {

  private Game game;

  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() {
    var tool = new Tool();
    var player = new Player(tool);
    game = new Game(player);
  }

  @Test
  void getPlayer() {
    var gamePlayer = game.getPlayer();
    assertEquals("player1", gamePlayer);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to inject a real Player object, not a mock Player

Comment: Then @InjectMock is not what you need. Mocks is not a real objects

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have tests design issue instead of how to inject your dependencies. The purpose of a unit test is to isolate and test at the best case, one functionality or one class. Here you have to isolate your Game test and test it only.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class GameTest {

  @Mock
  private Player player;

  @InjectMocks
  private Game game;
  
  @Test
  void testGetPlayer() {
    when(player.getPlayer()).thenReturn("player");
    var gamePlayer = game.getPlayer();
    assertEquals("player", gamePlayer);
  }
}
```

We use `@InjectMocks` for the class `undertest`, so here `Game`. Apply separation of concerns here.

Comment: That's a fair point. I guess the reason why I'm doing this is because I want to avoid having to mock all the `Player` functions while testing `Game`. Perhaps Mockito wasn't designed for this

Comment: I understand your point, don't worry about the fact you have to mock your methods. This is the role of mocking frameworks. Also to have a good designed unit test, you have to do it this way.